# Read Content of texfile separated by a Delimiters

Tags: java, regex

"John","100.00","200.00"

How to read the content of text file and then print string under quotes.

The output should be 
Jhon    100.00 200.00

```
String CUSTOMER, CURRENT, NEW;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        CUSTOMER = sc.next();
        CURRENT = sc.next();
        NEW = sc.next();
           System.out.println("" + CUSTOMER + " " + CURRENT + 
             " " + NEW);  
          }
          sc.close();
```

How to separate the tokens from quotes. output for above code which I am getting is this
"Jhon" "100.00" "200.00"

Comment: You forgot to post the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?? Share with us.

Comment: That looks like CSV data, so use a CSV Parser!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to accomplish the task:

```
String line, customerName, currentVal, newVal;
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("salesrep.txt"))) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        line = sc.nextLine().replace("\"", "");
        //skip blank lines (if any)
        if (line.equals("")) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] lineData = line.split(",");
        customerName = lineData[0];
        currentVal = lineData[1]; // or:  double currentVal = Double.parseDouble(lineData[1]);
        newVal = lineData[2];     // or:  double newVal = Double.parseDouble(lineData[2]);
        System.out.println("" + customerName + " " + currentVal + " " + newVal);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required output with following :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\\"(.*?)\\\".*?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("\"John\",\"100.00\",\"200.00\"");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Explain**

```
.*?   - anything
\\\" - quote (escaped)
(.*?) - anything (captured)
\\\" - another quote
.*?  - anything
```

**Output**

```
John
100.00
200.00
```

Comment: I am getting from a file so how to make it work for input from a file

Comment: You can get an idea by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/5454585)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

The scanner can also use delimiters other than whitespace. This example reads several items in from a string:

```
 String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
```

So you can avoid first and last quote by substring(1,len-1) and useDelimiter(\",\") with 3-symbols delim in inner part.

```
    String str = "\"John\",\"100.00\",\"200.00\"";
    System.out.println(str);
    String CUSTOMER, CURRENT, NEW;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(
        str.substring(1,str.length()-1)  // <--- here substring 
    );
    sc.useDelimiter("\",\""); // <---- here your split: <token>","<token>

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        CUSTOMER = sc.next();
        CURRENT = sc.next();
        NEW = sc.next();
        System.out.println("" + CUSTOMER + " " + CURRENT + " " + NEW);  
    }
    sc.close();
```